# jquery show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

look I have this question, how can i do something like this (look at images)

I think it's possible to do with jQuery or ajax, but i don't know how..

1. i have page something like this :
   [image]
2. when i click on 1st green cube slides up one #div container at the bottom of page :
   [image]
3. when i click on red 1st cude #div container at the bottom of page slides down :
   [image]
4. but when i click for example (on image 2) at the green cube #div container at the bottom slides down and up with new information abou title 2.

I hope so you will help me with this..

**And one more thing, when i click o green cube it color chancing to red, and when i click on red cube it's changes back to green.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly what you need, but I did a quick solution in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Z66Y/3/

If you click in the squares the bottom bar slides up and down, the only thing that is missing is the text, you could do that using the data attribute in every div and setting it to the bar innerHTML.

If the example is in the right track tell me and I'll add the data if you need it, but I don't know if you need to retrieve the data from somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write in the second green's jquery code that hide first green's bar, and do the opposite for the first green's jquery code.

like:

```
$("first").click(function(){
    $("second").hide();
    $("first").toggle();
});
$("second").click(function(){
    $("first").hide();
    $("second").toggle();
});
```

Comment: added example for my comment.

Comment: hmm, but if it will be about 200 green cubes ? i think then that code will not work.

Comment: i'd do it with showing an empty red bar and displaying the regarding message for the div when it's shown. This way you just have to go through the messages, for example adding them to your markup as `<a alt="This is the message" href="#">` read out the alt field of the `this` jquery command and put the read out message with a text()/html() function from the jQuery library.